# Wifi blocked by hardware (rl3290). rf kill unblock dosn't work

Tags: wireless

i recently migrated to ubuntu but wifi is not working. i checked and found that my wlan is blocked by hardware. i have already tried the rf kill unblock all method by it dosn't solve the problem. please help me someone. i have already tried many things but couldn't solve the problem. I have hp pavilion sleekbook 14 pc and i have RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe card. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My wifi is neither hard blocked nor soft blocked but on boot wifi does not work and the wifi button does not turn it back on. I have to manually start the `network-manager` with:

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

if `start` doesn't work you could use `restart`

Note this only a workaround for the meantime (well at least for me it is).
I have failed to by my lack of available free time, but you can create a program that executes at boot the command to start `network-manager`.

P.S. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: btw I have HP pavilion sleekbook 14 also

Comment: To make the process more *automagic* have you tried inserting your command into `/etc/rc.local`?